# find unique one-to-one relationship in two lists

Tags: python, list, unique

I am new to python and I currently have one text file that I sliced into two columns. I am looking for unique one-to-one relationships in the text file to determine new home buyers:

**Main File**

1234 Address ,  Billy Joel

Joe Martin, 45 Other Address

63 OtherOther Address, Joe Martin

Billy Joel, 1234 Address

***I am lookng for the unique one-to-one relationship (1234 Address and Billy Joel)***

**Curent Steps/Goals:**

> 1. sliced text file into two lists based on the ','

Looking to write something like this (I know this is very horribly laid out, but I am stuck on how to implement this):

```
addressListing= text file that is read

leftLst = addressListing.split(",", 1)[0]
rightLst = addressListing.split(".", 1) [1]    

for (x, y) in (leftLst, rightLst):
        if x in rightLst and y in leftLst:
             return x + y
        else:
             pass
```

The text file is not neat where there are only addresses on one side and only names on the other.

Comment: What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: Do you have a way of determining whether something is a name or an address? Once that exists, sets and/or dictionaries are good data structures for a problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}

for line in content:
    line = line.split(",")
    if len(line) == 2:
        left = line[0].strip()
        right = line[1].strip()

        dict1[left] = right
        dict2[right] = left

for k, v in dict1.items():
    if v in dict2 and dict2[v] == k:
        print("Match found: " + k + ", " + v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the adequat data structure for this problem. First off, consider using a [database](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) when items stored in a file are meant to have relationships.

Although, if all you require is a one time parsing of the file, using a `dict` should be sufficient and yet efficient enough.

### Code

```
def find_one_to_one(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v in d and d[v] == k:
            return k, v
    else:
        return None

with open('test_file.txt') as file:
    d = {left.strip(): right.strip() for left, right in [row.split(',') for row in file]}
    print(find_one_to_one(d))
```

### Test file content

```
1234 Address , Billy Joel
Joe Martin, 45 Other Address
63 OtherOther Address, Joe Martin
Billy Joel, 1234 Address
```

### Output

```
('1234 Address', 'Billy Joel')
```